# SSHing into a Ubuntu VM instance

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I have an Ubuntu VM instance running on my laptop. Both Host and VM run the same OS - Ubuntu 12.04. I tried to ssh from host like

```
ssh username@<VM-IP>
```

It tries for some time and then says

```
ssh: connect to host <ip-address> port 22: Connection timed out
```

Then I tried to 
ping

I get `100% packet loss`. Which I guess is because there is no established route.
How should I fix this?

Comment: You have to add a rule to map the VM ssh port into the host or change your VM network configuration to use a virtual bridge. Which software are you using to run the VM?

Comment: @salva I am using Oracle's Virtual Box

Comment: What is the VM IP address you are trying to connect to? Is it 10.0.2.15?

Comment: @Kenster Yes. That's the IP I was trying.

Answer (score 0):

**Easy way**: go to "network settings", "port forwarding" and add a rule to map VM port 22 to, for instance, port 9022 on the host. Then run `ssh localhost -p 9022`.

**Better way**: install Ubuntu `lxc` package, then, on VirtualBox, go to the VM `Network settings`, set `Attached to` to `Bridged Adapter`, set `Name` to `lxcbr0`, reboot the virtual machine and it would get a new IP reachable from the host. Though, if you do that, never start an LXC container and a VirtualBox VM attached to the same bridge at the same time or the host might go nuts (quite ugly bug somewhere)

Answer (score 0):

Go in to network settings in Virutalbox and change the network adapter to either bridged or host only. Make sure the VM's IP address is on the same subnet as the host's.

Answer (score 0):

Chech if you did install `openssh-server` server .

`sudo apt-get install openssh-server`

then check you have proper port enabled

`/etc/ssh/sshd_config` if you go in it with different port number from outside or your router has a rule of forwarding it to another port

you may also need to uncomment in there if you want to be authorized by password.

`#PasswordAuthentication yes`

Have the same port (default 22) enabled for forwarding in your virtual machine network configuration